# Informatica 10 - Delete files that have a space in the name

Tags: informatica-powercenter

How do you delete files with a space in the name?

I have a mapping that will update a table with the file names that fail the naming convention.

I use this table to create a .bat file to hold their names.

This is the code I run in a command to delete all the unwanted files.  If works fine if the files do not have a space in the name:

$$DRIVE_MAIN & CD $$IN_FOLDER & for /F %A in (DELETE_list.dat) do del %A

If the file has a space in the name it does not work.  I have tried to put double quotes around the file name as they get loaded into the table e.g. “Load ed_part1.csv”.  So, when it gets written out to the .bat file it is “Load ed_part1.csv”.

Unfortunately it still wont get deleted.

What am I missing.

Cheers

C

Comment: So, the problem with spaces in the occurs because its users who are creating the files.  

If the process had been automated I would have been able to raise an issue about the spaces.

You cannot cover for human error.

The solution was creating a spread sheet with VBA that checked the folder where the files were.  The VBA check the file name structure.

Guess what?.  They dont use the bl**dy spread sheet to do a final check on the filenames (haha)

Answer (score 0):

try putting the double quotes in the script - not in the file:

> $$DRIVE_MAIN & CD $$IN_FOLDER & for /F %A in (DELETE_list.dat) do del
>   “%A“